# How to add ToS to stream by using setsockopt?

Tags: c, sockets, stream, sip

First of all, I googled a lot and this is my last resort.

I use Linphone SIP open source for **Windows 7** and I try to send audio/video Streams with ToS different from 0.

The relevant part of code:

```
retval = setsockopt(session->rtp.socket, proto, value_type, (SOCKET_OPTION_VALUE)&tos, sizeof(tos));
        if (retval==-1)
            ortp_error("Fail to set DSCP value on rtp socket: %s",getSocketError());
        if (session->rtcp.socket != (ortp_socket_t)-1){
            if (setsockopt(session->rtcp.socket, proto, value_type, (SOCKET_OPTION_VALUE)&tos, sizeof(tos))==-1){
                ortp_error("Fail to set DSCP value on rtcp socket: %s",getSocketError());
            }
        }
```

I get success, a.e `retval` is not `-1`. However from wireshark I still see Tos = 0.

[Someone tells its windows bug, someone - by SPEC (a.e. feature).](http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?274421-Windows-7-resets-DiffServ-%28DSCP%29-to-0x00&p=2378071&viewfull=1#post2378071)

Does someone knows workaround or I need create manually group policy through "gpedit.msc" through command line?

Comment: what does WSAGetLastError value tell you?

Comment: see my edit, I don't get any error

Comment: For what it's worth, the TOS field is basically unused. Very few routers actually take any action on it.

Comment: maybe, but in my case get 70% packet loss because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "latest and greatest" QOS story from Microsoft, you need to look into [qWave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The problem with qWave is that the API in only half the story.  qWave allows you to "mark" the tcp flow types (video, voice, etc) for windows itself and then network administrator can create [polices](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb878009) about what to do about it.  Also qWave is not installed by default on server OSes.  What you can't do with qWave is set specific DSCP bits in the network packets, the bits set are defined by the Digital Living Network Alliance (DLNA) and the WiFi Alliance Wireless Multimedia (WMM) specification.

If you require the setting of specific DSCP bits, your only option is to use the older and deprecated [Traffic Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.